# Environment variables for packages built in custom location

Tags: environment-variables

Some time ago (month or so) I started to install packages that I build from source in custom location `~/.local` so that I can easily distinguish which I build from source, and for other reasons, although I'm single user

Also I'm new to Linux, and learned couple of things on the way. I use `checkinstall` on Ubuntu whenever I can, except for Python packages because it seems they clash with `easy-install.pth` for some reason. Building deb packages by myself is still far reach for me.

I have this now in my `.bashrc`:

```
export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/.local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/:$PYTHONPATH
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$HOME/.local/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
export MANPATH=$HOME/.local/share/man:$MANPATH
```

Today I was building something that was depending on header files from package I had built from source, and had trouble with it, until I found that I need to point C include path variable to the "local" include path path: `C_INCLUDE_PATH=$HOME/.local/include`

So I thought to ask more experienced users, did I miss some variable, that might introduce problems in future when some package depends on package installed in my custom folder?